# caching views with laravel to optimize disk i/o

Tags: php, caching, laravel

I have a tiny subview/partial in laravel ***which is loaded in a foreach loop***. I want to keep it in a separate view because in the future I will expand it and I don't want to litter my main view with the code. However, since it's a partial it takes a toll when it is loaded from the disk every time.

The question is: **How do I cache a view and pass new data to it without having to read it from disk every time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and manually create a new view. It should work but note that this is totally untested:

```
<?php
    $view = View::make('your-partial');
    foreach($data as $model){
        $v = clone $view;
        $v->with('data', $model);
        echo $v->render();
    }
?>
```

### Edit

I just dug a bit deeper and found out that the above won't help much with the issue. The view file is not being read until you call `render()` so the code above will still read the file for each iteration.

`render()` calls `getContents()` that calls `get()` on the engine and then again that calls `evaluatePath`:

```
protected function evaluatePath($__path, $__data)
{
    $obLevel = ob_get_level();

    ob_start();

    extract($__data);

    // We'll evaluate the contents of the view inside a try/catch block so we can
    // flush out any stray output that might get out before an error occurs or
    // an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
    try
    {
        include $__path;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
    }

    return ltrim(ob_get_clean());
}
```

---

If you really have to reduce the reads I'd say your only option is to put the partial view code directly into the other view.

Comment: hmm that sucks.. the reads cause a 400% increase in load time. It's not ***that*** bad since we're working with miliseconds and on the production server everything is on SSD's.. but still.. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: And the partial is too big to have it directly in the view?

Comment: As it is now, no. But according to the roadmap it will be bigger. But then I'll just break up the view at a different place if necessary.

Comment: I see. I would go with that strategy. For example you could move the loop itself as well into the partial. This way the code is still separated but the partial only needs to be included once :)